# Mac OSX Core Data App - Cannot turn on iCloud Capability

Tags: macos, core-data, icloud, ensembles

I have a published Mac app which uses Core Data and I am in the beginning stages of implementing iCloud (Documents) to sync data between devices (using Ensembles). When I attempt to turn on iCloud the app does not run. It builds successfully and then says it has finished running. This message appears in the Console: 
`Message from debugger: unable to attach`
If I turn off the iCloud capability it will run successfully with no issues.
I am logged into iCloud, and there are no issues shown in the setup. Any ideas as to why I cannot use the iCloud capability? The same issue occurs if I try to activate Push Notifications (even with iCloud Off).

[iCloud Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY1Uw.png)
[iCloud Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NYnL.png)

Comment: This sounds like you are having issues with Xcode's built in provisioning. Make sure that your team is setup properly in the Preferences of Xcode, and selected in the the Target settings. Also go to provisioning portal and check settings there.

Comment: Thankyou Drew, you have put me in the right direction. I checked your suggested items and they looked ok. But something I hadn't checked was my TargetTests settings, I turned on signing here and this appears to have worked.